# Is it safe to export sql database to my PC?

Tags: mysql, sql, security

Can someone intercept it like man in the middle or something like that?
What's the drill when you want to backup your database with all the user info onto your hard drive?

Should I encrypt it? My phpMyAdmin runs under SSL so I guess connection is encrypted.

Comment: You should be fine with SSL. But... maybe not such a cool idea to have unencrypted user info sitting on your hard drive though. Do you have enough room on the server that you could SSH, dump, zip, encrypt and store it there? Or rsync/sftp it somewhere safe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you are interested in moving your production database into your local PC for development purposes, and that you are concerned about protecting your end users from prying eyes. You highlight a number of valid concerns about how the data might be intercepted, but there is something that you seem to not realize: **Exporting your production database to your developer machine is in-and-of-itself a breach of your application's security, even if nobody else knows about it.** Your users expect that their data remain hidden from everyone, including you as a (presumably well-intentioned) developer! Using their personal data for your own purposes--no matter how honorable you may think your purposes are--is a violation of those expectations. With the exception of creating backups solely for the purpose of recovering from catastrophic data-loss events (failing hard drives in production, botched patches, and whatnot), you should *never* be sending raw dumps of your production data anywhere. (And sure, when you do create those backups, you should probably encrypt them.)

Getting back to the assumption that you want to protect your end-users' data, your best bet against malicious entities is to implement [data masking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_masking) on sensitive data. This is where you export the relational contents of your schemata with data that won't compromise the identities or intent of your actual, real-world users. Essentially, you replace names and e-mail addresses with spoof identities, and anything else that could be classified as "confidential" (which you will need to determine on your own) is similarly redacted and/or replaced with fake data.

The advantages to data-masking should be immediately apparent. Even if (god forbid!) someone were to intercept your backup and try to deduce information about your users from it, all they would end up with is a set of fictional data, which cannot be used to infer anything about your actual users. Of course, if they did intercept your dump somehow, they could easily reverse-engineer your schema, and that would be a trouble in-and-of-itself, but at least they won't immediately have access to the private details of your userbase. That said, there are a number of reasonably secure ways to transmit data these days, such as FTP over SSL (aka FTPS). (Note that FTPS is *not* the same as SFTP!)

Comment: While your answer is correct I want to add an additional clarification that FTP over SSL (well actually it's TLS) layer is actually *not the same* as SFTP, I have met far too many people who seem to think that the SFTP == FTPS.

Comment: @Martin Yes, you are correct. I will append that to my answer just for repetition's sake.

Comment: So if I export an SQL database for the purpose of recovering from data-loss, it's not a breach of security? I mean, I don't wanna do anything illegal. I just need to export it somewhere on a weekly basis so in case a db gets messed up I can reset it to the last exported database.

Comment: Exporting your SQL database for the sake of having a backup in case something goes wrong is a very good practice. You should do it often, in fact; as often as you can bare. What's bad is when those backups are being used for other purposes, even if those "other purposes" are pure-hearted (such as wanting to develop upon the data). Many organizations do it because it's convenient, but that doesn't make it right. Also, when it comes to legality, that largely depends upon the jurisdiction your organization falls under and your contracts with your users... but in general, I'd say it isn't illegal.